# Java checksum method

Tags: java, checksum

so I've been working on a checksum method where i take 4 binary numbers and convert them to decimal, add them together, covert the sum to binary again and calculate the checksum. Here is my code, i didn't know how to do the last part using java which is calculating the checksum

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


        String a = "1010000001000011";
        String b = "1111100101001111";
        String c = "1111111111101110";
        String d = "1110101011111110";

        int aa = Integer.parseInt(a, 2);        
        int bb = Integer.parseInt(b,2);
        int cc = Integer.parseInt(c,2);
        int dd = Integer.parseInt(d,2);

        int f = aa + bb + cc + dd;
        StringBuffer buf =  new StringBuffer();

        while (f!=0){
            int digit = f%2;
            buf.append(digit);
            f=f/2;
        }
        buf.reverse();
}
```

Comment: There's a ready method that does it for you.

Comment: @Teemu My OCD almost killed me because of your profile picture.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What sort of checksum do you want to compute? You have a binary number that can be stored in 4 (actually 3) bytes. You could use even or odd parity over 4 (3) bytes. Or a Cyclic Redundancy Checksum, for which there is a JDK class (CRC32). Or...

Comment: I want a method to calculate the checksum at the sender and verify the checksum at the receiver.

Comment: @John_Welfrade Did you try my solution? It works?

Answer (score 1):

To convert the number to a string again, you can use `Integer.toString(number, 2)`. That results in a string on which you can call `.hashCode()` to get it's hash code / check sum.

EDIT:
Instead of `Integer.toString(number, 2)` you can use `Integer.toBinaryString(number)`, which is a bit faster and also reads easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try method:

```
//your code
...
int f = aa + bb + cc + dd;
Integer.toBinaryString(f)
```